# Swift 5 Circle Button (Programmatically)

Tags: swift, swift5, xcode11

I am trying to code a circular button programmatically, but it always ends up as a square. I have tried several things and looked everywhere but do not know what else to do.
The second part of the code is in another class.

```
static let warriorButton: UIButton = {

    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = .blue
    button.setTitle("WARRIOR", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    button.isEnabled = true

    return button
}()



warriorButton.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 100, paddingLeft: 60, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 90, height: 90)
warriorButton.layer.cornerRadius = warriorButton.layer.bounds.size.width/2;
warriorButton.clipsToBounds = true;
```

Comment: Try adding `warriorButton.layer.masksToBounds = true` and you might need `warriorButton.isOpaque = true`

Comment: Show `func anchor(top: ...` code

Comment: Add `warriorButton.layoutIfNeeded()` before `warriorButton.layer.cornerRadius`

Answer (score 2):

It's too early to use button width before  `viewDidLayoutSubviews`  so either

```
warriorButton.layer.cornerRadius = 45
warriorButton.clipsToBounds = true
```

OR inside

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
   super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    warriorButton.layer.cornerRadius = warriorButton.frame.size.width/2     
    warriorButton.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line to your code

```
yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = yourButton.frame.height/2
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your code

```
warriorButton.clipsToBounds = true
warriorButton.layer.cornerRadius = warriorButton.frame.size.width / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

2021 Answer:

```swift
Button(action: {}) {
    Text("WARRIOR")
}.foregroundColor(Color.white)
.padding(30)
.background(
    Circle()
    .fill(Color.blue)
)
```